# Setting up an open directory master on OS X Lion Server for the first time: LDAP issue

Tags: macos, directory, ldap

We have a server running as an open directory master. So far it has been perfectly fine: users can access their data via VPN or network accounts on client machines. However, the LDAP log consistently reports errors. I've attached the log below:

```
Sep 12 13:01:54 server slapd[61]: conn=6890 op=27: attribute "entryCSN" index add failure
Sep 12 13:01:56 server slapd[61]: Entry (uid=untitled_1,cn=users,dc=server,dc=speirhunter,dc=private): object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 13:01:56 server slapd[61]: entry failed schema check: object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 13:04:55 server slapd[61]: => bdb_idl_delete_key: c_get failed: DB_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Locker killed to resolve a deadlock (-30994)
Sep 12 13:04:55 server slapd[61]: conn=6916 op=23: attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure
Sep 12 13:04:56 server slapd[61]: Entry (uid=untitled_1,cn=users,dc=server,dc=speirhunter,dc=private): object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 13:04:56 server slapd[61]: entry failed schema check: object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 13:12:43 server slapd[61]: => nestedgroup_getgroup result (16)
Sep 12 13:41:11 server slapd[61]: => bdb_idl_delete_key: c_get failed: DB_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Locker killed to resolve a deadlock (-30994)
Sep 12 13:41:11 server slapd[61]: conn=7113 op=15: attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure
Sep 12 13:41:12 server slapd[61]: Entry (uid=untitled_1,cn=users,dc=server,dc=speirhunter,dc=private): object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 13:41:12 server slapd[61]: entry failed schema check: object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 14:17:48 server slapd[61]: => nestedgroup_getgroup result (16)
Sep 12 14:29:46 server slapd[61]: => nestedgroup_getgroup result (16)
Sep 12 14:30:55 server slapd[61]: => nestedgroup_getgroup result (16)
Sep 12 14:31:26: --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Sep 12 14:36:30 server slapd[61]: => nestedgroup_getgroup result (16)
Sep 12 14:38:56: --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Sep 12 14:39:37 server slapd[61]: => nestedgroup_getgroup result (16)
Sep 12 14:40:34: --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Sep 12 14:40:34 server slapd[61]: => nestedgroup_getgroup result (16)
Sep 12 14:43:21 server slapd[61]: => nestedgroup_getgroup result (16)
Sep 12 14:51:47 server slapd[61]: => nestedgroup_getgroup result (16)
Sep 12 14:54:35: --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Sep 12 14:54:35 server slapd[61]: connection_read(22): no connection!
Sep 12 15:35:49 server slapd[61]: => nestedgroup_getgroup result (16)
Sep 12 15:36:27: --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Sep 12 16:45:10 server slapd[62]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.23 (Feb 25 2012 19:47:01) $
                root@melodie.apple.com:/private/var/tmp/OpenLDAP/OpenLDAP-186.4~2/servers/slapd
Sep 12 16:45:10 server slapd[62]: daemon: SLAP_SOCK_INIT: dtblsize=8192
Sep 12 16:45:11 server slapd[62]: bdb_monitor_db_open: monitoring disabled; configure monitor database to enable
Sep 12 16:45:11 server slapd[62]: slapd starting
Sep 12 16:45:11 server slapd[62]: daemon: posting com.apple.slapd.startup notification
Sep 12 16:53:06 server slapd[62]: => bdb_idl_delete_key: c_get failed: DB_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Locker killed to resolve a deadlock (-30994)
Sep 12 16:53:06 server slapd[62]: conn=1216 op=19: attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure
Sep 12 16:53:07 server slapd[62]: Entry (uid=untitled_1,cn=users,dc=server,dc=speirhunter,dc=private): object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 16:53:07 server slapd[62]: entry failed schema check: object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 17:09:40 server slapd[62]: => bdb_idl_delete_key: c_get failed: DB_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Locker killed to resolve a deadlock (-30994)
Sep 12 17:09:40 server slapd[62]: conn=1366 op=19: attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure
Sep 12 17:09:41 server slapd[62]: Entry (uid=untitled_1,cn=users,dc=server,dc=speirhunter,dc=private): object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 17:09:41 server slapd[62]: entry failed schema check: object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 17:11:25 server slapd[62]: Entry (uid=sadmin,cn=users,dc=server,dc=speirhunter,dc=private): object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 17:11:25 server slapd[62]: entry failed schema check: object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 17:19:53 server slapd[62]: => bdb_idl_delete_key: c_get failed: DB_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Locker killed to resolve a deadlock (-30994)
Sep 12 17:19:53 server slapd[62]: conn=1420 op=788: attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure
Sep 12 17:19:54 server slapd[62]: Entry (uid=untitled_1,cn=users,dc=server,dc=speirhunter,dc=private): object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 17:19:54 server slapd[62]: entry failed schema check: object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 18:19:30 server slapd[62]: <= bdb_substring_candidates: (altSecurityIdentities) not indexed
Sep 12 18:21:21 server slapd[62]: => bdb_idl_delete_key: c_get failed: DB_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Locker killed to resolve a deadlock (-30994)
Sep 12 18:21:21 server slapd[62]: conn=2057 op=55: attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure
Sep 12 18:21:22 server slapd[62]: Entry (uid=untitled_1,cn=users,dc=server,dc=speirhunter,dc=private): object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 18:21:22 server slapd[62]: entry failed schema check: object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 18:25:09 server slapd[62]: => bdb_idl_delete_key: c_get failed: DB_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Locker killed to resolve a deadlock (-30994)
Sep 12 18:25:09 server slapd[62]: conn=2095 op=61: attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure
Sep 12 18:25:10 server slapd[62]: Entry (uid=untitled_1,cn=users,dc=server,dc=speirhunter,dc=private): object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
Sep 12 18:25:10 server slapd[62]: entry failed schema check: object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
```

Can anyone shed some light as to what this means, and some possible causes for it?

Answer (score 0):

You've posted many  error messages. First, you can try to lower verbosity in slapd.conf, if everything you need to be working - works, I wouldn't care. Second, if you really need to fix these, you need to examine each issue - some of them shown here relate to invalid indexing configuration, some of them require to fix something with nested group concept, and some are related to schema not matching objects. Did you turn schema check on? AFAIR from some slapd version it's on by default. What version do you use?

Use slaptest utility to test consistency of your database and/or configfile, and slapcat for dumping database, and you could have realized it after first try of recovery after something wrong happens. Some errors you've presented may have influence on dumping database, making in unable to be dumped. Check/rebuild indexes with slapindex too.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is pretty easy to spot:

```
Entry (uid=untitled_1,cn=users,dc=server,dc=speirhunter,dc=private): object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'

entry failed schema check: object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'homeDirectory'
```

You have an entry of class `posixAccount` which is incomplete as it does not specify the `homeDirectory` attribute. A posix account is what you would normally call *user*. Such entries are the open directory equivalent of an entry in the `/etc/passwd`. But that entry misses the home directory field (attribute, in LDAP parlance).

As it's `untitled_1` it's probably some bogus entry. You may want to either add the homeDirectory attribute or remove the entry altogether. You may also want to hunt down how it got there and how it got there in an invalid format (do you have some tool that created it? where does that untitled_1 come from?)